# Git status is clean even though a file has changed

Tags: windows, git, github

I have spent a great deal of time since I first started using Git struggling with files being reported as changed when they hadn't been touched, and `core.filemode = false` resolved those issues... but today I have the reverse problem. (Unless otherwise specified, I'm doing this from Git Bash (1.7.10.msysgit.1) in Windows 7.)

The situation:

1. On my `master` branch, I did `git pull upstream master` to pull the latest changes - this said everything was up to date (I double-checked and the last commit is the same on my local master, my origin fork and the upstream Github repo so I'm reasonably certain this is correct)
2. I amended an existing file. The diff in TortoiseGit 1.8.0.0 shows the changes, though its overlay still shows the directory as clean. Odd. `git status` is... still clean. Very odd.
3. I delete a file: `rm Readme.md`. File disappears. `git status` is still clean. Clearly, git isn't actually tracking my files anymore.

(For the record, setting `core.filemode = true` and then running `git status` just gave me nonsense about files whose mode changed at some point between my Windows system and Github, but still didn't list the deleted or the truly modified files)

I'm missing something here and I hope someone can tell me what it is! I've done dozens of commits from this machine to that same repository via my fork on Github so I'm reasonably certain this environment works and I generally know what I'm doing, but clearly something has changed that I can't put my finger on right now.

Edit, as requested, my Git workflow as followed in Bash (didn't bother checking out a new branch as the problem occurs in master anyway):

```
Emma Burrows@PC ~/Documents/Dropbox/gitproject (test)
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

Emma Burrows@PC ~/Documents/Dropbox/gitproject (master)
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Emma Burrows@PC ~/Documents/Dropbox/gitproject (master)
$ git pull upstream master
From git://github.com/company/gitproject
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

Emma Burrows@PC ~/Documents/Dropbox/gitproject (master)
$ rm Readme.md

Emma Burrows@PC ~/Documents/Dropbox/gitproject (master)
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Readme.md is a tracked file present in both my forked repo on Github and in the original upstream repo. I hope that helps?

**NEW EDIT** I've moved the folder out of Dropbox to a local folder on a local drive, but the problem remains the same. The .git folder must be poked. I was hoping to find out what was wrong with it though.

Comment: Can you paste some bash output to show us your workflow and what git is doing?

Comment: Done. Does that help? The problem isn't specific to a new branch so I just did it all in master.

Comment: Is the working folder on a network share, which version of TortoiseGit are you running?

Comment: The working folder is local (though as you can see by its path, connected to Dropbox - I've disabled Dropbox synching to troubleshoot this problem). TortoiseGit is probably not relevant since I'm doing all this (except the Diff) in Git Bash for Windows (1.7.10.msysgit.1), but it's TortoiseGit 1.8.0.0.

Comment: Dropbox huh. Here's a thing for you to try. `rm` the file and go make a cup of tea. When you come back, run git status and see if git picks up the change. Do this with Dropbox sync ON.

Comment: Can you run the commnad `git ls-files` and check if the Readme.md is present in the list?

Comment: That's interesting. I did `rm Readme.md` in Git Bash and the file disappeared from the Dropbox folder in Windows Explorer. But then doing the `git ls-files >log.log` (too many files to scroll back through), Readme.md is still listed. (And `git status` does pick up on the existence of the new untracked log.log file)

Comment: Well, git will keep tracking Readme.md until you `git rm` it. The real question is why you're rm'ing it and git isn't seeing the discrepancy. I think the reason might be Dropbox syncing. Try moving the repo onto a non-Dropbox local location and see if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Probably @JosefAssad are right. Try to remove from Dropbox.

Comment: Is your current partition out of space? This might happen if git is not able to write anything. You can also check for a possible permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who tried to help. The problem persisted after I moved the whole folder, including .git folder into another location on my local hard drive. I can only assume that two copies of the repo on different machines had tried to sync the git folder at once and resulted in a broken local repo. I ended up recloning the folder (out of Dropbox for now) and everything is working normally again.